# Gap between the first X datetime value and the Y axis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

In my application, I use mschart to display data using a x axis with datetime value and an Y axis with numeric (double) values.

However, I have noticed that there is a small gap between the Y axis and the first X value:

[image]

Is there a way to force the graph to start exactly on the Y axis?

**EDIT:** Here is what I use to populate my series:

```
foreach (AggregatedValue value in line.Value)
{
    series.Points.AddXY(value.TimeStamp.ToLocalTime(), value.Value);
}
```

Aggregated value is a class containing the 2 x, y properties, TimeStamp (datetime) and Value (double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,
I had to set manually the Minimum and Maximum value for my x-axis, using

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum and chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum
```