# Chart control - Gap between first X value and Y-axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I'm using a line chart to plot some values, where the x-axis has a set of strings and the y-axis has a double value between 0 and 1. Everything works correctly except there is a gap between the first x value and the y-axis 
[the image shows.](http://prntscr.com/3ue533)

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841761/gap-between-the-first-x-datetime-value-and-the-y-axis)  the solution is setting the x-axis maximum and minimum value. However, I can't seem to do it in this case as the values are strings and not doubles / dates.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using strings, this may or may not help. Try setting the IsXValueIndexed property of your underlying series to be false.

See this MSDN article for reference:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the margin you need to set

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```